# Issue hosting ASP.NET Core 2.0 on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I'm setting up a server to host an application I made with ASP.NET Core 2.0.3. I'll be running this application on a [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) R2 server, using IIS 8.5. I followed [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1) to set up the environment.

If I run `(dir (Get-Command dotnet).Path.Replace('dotnet.exe', 'shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App')).Name` in PowerShell.

It tells me I'm running the right version of the runtime environment and by running `dotnet MyProject.dll` it runs the project on port 5000 and I can access it from the server. But when accessing with the server URL, this is the page I see:

[image]

The .NET CLR Version of the application pool is set to *No Managed Code* and this is my *web.config* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url=".*" />
               <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
         <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3221225472" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tried to remove the rewrite rules and nothing changes. And there is no error log created.

I'm lost on what else I can try. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure that you have UrlRewrite IIS extension installed.
2. Ensure that Application Pool identity user IIS AppPool{AppPoolName} must have read permissions on the published website folder

Go to your published website directory and search for Application Pool Identity user which has format IIS AppPool{AppPool Name} e.g. IIS AppPool\DefaultWebsite and give it read permissions

[image]

In IIS Manager select your website in the left pane and then in right pane double click the HandlerMappings icon to ensure that handlers list show up.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The permissions are OK but when I go to the handler mappings they don't show up, I get this message from IIS: "There was an error while performing this operation" with empty details

Comment: Have you ensured that UrlRewrite extension is installed on the server? Also, select your website in IIS Manger left pane and then double click the Authentication in the right pane. Right click `Anonymous Authentication` click Edit and then ensure `Application Pool Identity` is selected in the dialog box

Comment: Yesm UrlRewrite is installed. When I try to do what you said I get the same error I get when I'm at Handlers. If I delete the web.config then I can access the handlers and authentication. I'm reparing the runtime to check if that's the problem

Comment: Finally fixed. So these were the problems: 1 - The UrlRewrite was not installed, 2 - I repaired the runtime (control panel > uninstall > repair .Net Core runtime).

I have to repair because I has installed the latest one , 2.1.2 , the I had to dind the right one and install. I think this messed up the installation